# How to scope very last anchor in complex unknown level ul li menu

Tags: css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

i am looking for a way to scope the very last anchor displayed in a menu.
I'm trying to catch it up using css but no-avail. In my example, i am trying to scope the anchor written 'yes' witch is the last in the list, not the last of 'a parent'.

html :

```
<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">no</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">no</a></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">no</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">no</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">no</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">no</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">no</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">yes</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">no</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">no</a></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">no</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">no</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">no</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">no</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">no</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">yes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u2BTz/2/

Anyhow, i will accept the jQuery solution, any help **to scope this with only css** would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't really do this with a CSS selector.

Comment: @BoltClock, thanks, i just don't want to give up before ensuring with other users advices.

Answer (score 2):

Diodeus's answer is on the right track, but you have to implement a two-step matching operation if you want to take advantage of [last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/):

```
$(".container").each(function() {
    $(this).find("a").last().css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Otherwise, all the `<a>` elements will be matched, regardless of container, and `last()` will ony return the very last one of them.

Comment: accepted as for a solution still i wonder if it can be done with .css only

Comment: @Milche, I second BoltClock's comment here: to my knowledge, there is currently no way to match these elements in pure CSS. Even CSS3's `:last-of-type` does not take descendants into account, and `:last` is only supported by jQuery.

Comment: Merci Frédéric, j'apprécie.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the layers, just select the anchor tags directly.

```
$('.container a').last().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: Hi Diodeus, i forked your proposition here : http://jsfiddle.net/fwyd8/  but it seems to only grab the last of last and not the last of .container

Comment: Huh? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.